# Postgresql filter clause equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a postgresql `filter` clause equivalent in SQL Server? I am using SQL Server 2016.

https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/the-within-group-and-filter-sql-clauses-of-postgresql-9-4/#_the_code_filter_code_clause

Comment: I suppose you need to write case expressions instead. Not hard at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with `case`.  I don't know what you are trying to do, but for instance:

```
select count(*) filter (where state = 'NY')
```

would be:

```
select sum(case when state = 'NY' then 1 else 0 end)
```